# Derived type functionality in delegate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, delegates, variance

I want to write a method with signature `Expression<Func<T, bool>> Foo<T>()`. My class U inherits from T. I want to include U-specific processing in this delegate. The problem is, T can't be implicitly converted to U. Is there any way I can access U-specific properties in this method?

Complication: I also have type V : T which I want to be handled, so I can't just take advantage of variance by replacing T with U in the signature.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to move some of the needed functionality in type `U` to base type `T`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't due to the fact that not null discriminator columns must be mapped on children in EF :-/

Comment: Why can't you explicitly convert `T` to `U` in your method?

Comment: Entity framework doesn't allow edm types to be implicitly converted. I can write some implicit operators but I didn't know if there was another way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using separate overloads:  (),  (myVar) where T : U, and (myvar, myvar2) where T : V. That did the trick and I lucked out because each parameter is an app value that corresponds with an entity property.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to define an interface which both T and U inherit(Use it) from it.

Comment: Wouldn't that end up making me still have to implicitly convert to U in order to access U's fields?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, is T stands for  one of your objects or it stands as a generic object?

Comment: T is the top level class. I want to be able to access U-specific properties in the method. If I add an interface, I'll still either have to cast T to U to get access to U's properties, or I'll have to make T implement a shared U property, which is overkill because T shouldn't have U properties.